# Add character to string to get another string?

Tags: string, clojure

I want to add a character to a string, and get another string with the character added as a result.

This doesn't work:

```
(cons \a "abc")
```

Possible solutions, in order of preference:

1. Clojure core function
2. Clojure library function
3. Clojure user-defined (me!) function  (such as `(apply str (cons \a "abc"))`)
4. java.lang.String methods

Is there any **category 1** solution before I roll-my-own?

---

Edit:  this was a pretty dumb question.  **:(**

Comment: Well, sometimes Clojure functions don't have the clearest names. Also, while there is a `concat` function, it only works on collections, and strings are not collections. Thinking about this... why would they *not* be collections anyway? They're immutable Java strings after all.

Comment: Actually `concat` works on strings, it just doesn't return a string, but a sequence of characters. If I'm not mistaken you can use a string anywhere a collection is expected, but a sequence of characters is not automatically transformed back into a string.

Comment: If you want to transform seq of chars back to string--> (apply str char-seq)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

How about:

```
(str "abc" \a)
```

This returns "abca" on my machine.

You can also use it for any number of strings/chars: `(str "kl" \m "abc" \a \b)`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `join` from `clojure.string`:

`(clojure.string/join [\a "abc"])`

But for the simple use case you should really just use `str`, as @Dan Filimon suggests. `join` has the added benefit that you could put a separator between the joined strings, but without a separator it actually just applies `str`:

```
(defn ^String join
  "Returns a string of all elements in coll, separated by
   an optional separator.  Like Perl's join."
  {:added "1.2"}
  ([coll]
     (apply str coll))
  ([separator [x & more]]
     (loop [sb (StringBuilder. (str x))
            more more
            sep (str separator)]
       (if more
         (recur (-> sb (.append sep) (.append (str (first more))))
                (next more)
                sep)
         (str sb)))))
```